# List of graph layout algorithms

Tags: data-visualization, graphical-model

I am a newbie in visualizations. Nowadays, I regularly come across graph-based data that I need to visualize. However, different type of data requires different layouts. And as I do not have enough experience, I am not aware of the different graph layout algorithms.

I would like to have a list of graph layout algorithms with pseudo-code or code (in any language) that I can refer to when implementing some graph.

Comment: I think StackOverflow will give you better answers.

Answer (score 5):

1. Spring-Electric Force Directed
   Placement algorithm as explained in Efficient and High Quality
   Force-Directed Graph Drawing by Yifan Hu.
2. Buchheim Tree Drawing
3. Spring/Repulsion Model
4. Stress Majorization
5. Spectral Layout Algorithm

and many more with Julia code [here](https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/NetworkLayout.jl)

I am trying to write some of it using Java. There is a paper titled *Graph Drawing and Analysis Library and Its Domain-Specific Language for Graphs’ Layout Specifications* *by*
Renata Vaderna, Željko Vuković, Igor Dejanović, and Gordana Milosavljević in which they compare their [library](https://github.com/renatav/GraphDrawing) with other libraries like [JUNG](https://github.com/jrtom/jung).

There is enough code there to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the algorithms themselves rather than software which will just do it (of which there are many), check out some of the papers of [Yifan Hu](http://yifanhu.net/index.html), which give a nice introduction to certain types of algorithms (not exhaustive).

- [Algorithms for visualizing large networks](http://yifanhu.net/PUB/ch16.pdf)
- [Efficient and high quality graph drawing](http://yifanhu.net/PUB/graph_draw_small.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Gibson, Faith, and Vickers wrote a [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/20529851.pdf) comparing different relational graph layout techniques, analyzing where they excel and where they falter. While they don't contain pseudocode, they provide a good overview that you can then use to search for specific algorithms.

Comment: The link here links to this question (I guess the author made a mistake) - you can find the 2013 paper [here](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/1473871612455749)

Comment: @drevicko thanks, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing), the R package `igraph` has several algorithms that might provide nice leads/references, including layout.random, layout.circle, layout.sphere, layout.fruchterman.reingold, layout.kamada.kawai, layout.spring, layout.reingold.tilford, layout.fruchterman.reingold.grid, layout.lgl, layout.svd, and layout.norm